# Force Umbraco to set Home.aspx as the default document?

Tags: umbraco

I am desperately looking for a way to force (or even hack) Umbraco to set the default document to Content/Pages/Home.aspx, instead of the first page.

(Currently I created a dummy page that redirects to Home.aspx as the first page under Content - but it is not ideal especially for SEO)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easy to do, add a new field to your existing/current default document called 'umbracoInternalRedirectId', of type 'content-picker.'

While editing the content for that page, choose the contentpicker and point it to the page you want to be the default document and save/publish and you should be good to go.

Comment: I can't believe it's that easy. Thank you so much